# Flexbox - Aligning item 1 to be on top and item 2 and 3 to be on the bottom side by side

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to align a header to be centred at the top and an image and paragraph to be beneath the header side by side. So Item one is at the top, Item 2 is bottom left and Item 3 is bottom right.

Here's the code I have so far..

HTML:

```
<section>
<div class="container">
                <div class="gallery-flex">
                    <div class="owner-pic">
                        <h2>Meet The Director</h2>
                        <img src="images/gallery/me4.jpg" alt="#">
                        <p>Some text and shit more text and shit</p>
                    </div>
                    <h2>Here are some photos of the cars we have cleaned.</h2>
                    <div class="pic1">
                        <img src="images/gallery/cleaning-car01.png" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pic2">
                        <img src="images/gallery/cleaning-car02.jpg" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pic3">
                        <img src="images/gallery/cleaning-car03.jpg" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pic4">
                        <img src="images/gallery/cleaning-car04.jpg" alt="#">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pic5">
                        <img src="images/gallery/cleaning-car05.jpg" alt="#">
                    </div>
</div> <!--section-flex!-->
</div><!--container!-->
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.owner-pic {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

section .owner-pic h2 {
    align-self: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

section .owner-pic img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    align-self: flex-start;

}

section .owner-pic p {;
    align-self: flex-end;
    flex-grow: 2;
}
```

Comment: where is the html so far?

Comment: Added the HTML (I formatted it slightly wrong so apologies for that)

Comment: `<div class=<"gallery-flex">` ??

Comment: Some of the HTML is slightly wrong `<div class=<"gallery-flex">`

Comment: I amended that typo. What im trying to do is make the <h2> to be on top, <img> to be on bottom left and <p> to sit next to <img> on its right. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not too clear is it :

```css
.owner-pic {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.owner-pic h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
.owner-pic img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.owner-pic p {}
```

```html
<div class="owner-pic">
  <h2>Meet The Director</h2>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300" alt="#">
  <p>Some text and shhhh more text and shipsum</p>
</div>
```

or

```css
.owner-pic {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.owner-pic h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
.owner-pic img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.owner-pic p {}
```

```html
<div class="owner-pic">
  <h2>Meet The Director</h2>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300" alt="#">
  <p>Some text and shit more text and shit</p>
</div>
```

you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the `owner-pic` "header" then something like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
header h2 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
.child {
  flex:1;
  height: 100px;
  background: plum;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind I wrote this before the updated post. I figured you don't really need flexbox for everything. Kept it simple by placing content (`.img` and `.text`) in the flex container (`.flex`) then placing the header (`.title`) centered and on top. The styles for html and body are optional, they are defaults I normally use.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 500 16px/1.428'Verdana';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100vw;
}
img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.img {
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
.text {
  flex: 2 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>35733984</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header class="title">
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
  </header>
  <section class="flex">
    <figure class="img">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nightlife">
    </figure>
    <article class="text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel cu purto ancillae, in erat gubergren vim. Has in scripta vituperata, audiam option democritum eos et. His in agam mediocrem assentior, nusquam vituperata vituperatoribus ex vim. Vel ei equidem omittam. Vis ex quodsi
        voluptatum, cum semper commodo ceteros no, nec possim pertinax an.
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to every one giving me solutions! I'm still learning and I really got stuck here..

Heres the solution to my problem.

```
.owner-pic {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

section .owner-pic h2 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
}

section .owner-pic img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```